# In Symfony 1.2 how can I get the current database name from the database.yml file in Propel?

Tags: database, symfony1, propel

I have a raw sql query I need to run, but the database name changes in each environment (live: db, dev db_test)

I need to get the current database name from the databases.yml file.

How can I get just the current database name?

I am using the Propel ORM

Comment: Is it possible to use the current database connection, or do you really need the database name to create the connection yourself? If you use "regular" Propel you can use `Propel::getConnection()` to get a PDO connection, I think you can also do this in Symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I thought this would be pretty easy via `sfPropelDatabase::getConfiguration()` but that returns an array. As such, I had to parse the result to get the data, and I think there's probably a better way than this:

```
$propel_config = sfPropelDatabase::getConfiguration();
preg_match('/dbname=([^;]+);/', $propel_config['propel']['datasources']['propel']['connection']['dsn'], $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Anyone got anything better?

Comment: It would really be nice if there was more control beside just getting a dump for the yaml file.
I had to remove the ';' from the regex above since the dbname was the last character and it could not find it at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Propel2 -- essentially the same as the accepted answer.

```
$mgr = \Propel\Runtime\Propel::getConnectionManager($connectionId);
$dsn = $mgr->getConfiguration()['dsn'];
preg_match('/dbname=([^;]+)/', $dsn, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```